# #region analogue for eclipse

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, ide, region

can somebody tell me, is there an analogue of a Visual Studio #region feature for Eclipse IDE ?
I really need this magic! :)

Comment: Coffee-Bytes for Eclipse 3.6 & higher: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/what-code-folding-plugins-work-on-eclipse-3-6

Answer (score 20, accepted):

User-defined regions for code folding can be added by using the [Coffee-Bytes](http://code.google.com/p/coffee-bytes/) plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately that project is dead.

Comment: Looks like it is still available on google code...http://code.google.com/p/coffee-bytes/

Comment: Updated the link to remove the bootylicious domain squatter.

Comment: Coffee-Bytes does not work in Eclipse 3.6:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/any-good-code-folding-plugin-for-eclipse-3-6-the-coffee-bytes-code-folding-does

Answer (score 7):

[Coffee-Bytes plugin](http://themindstorms.blogspot.com/2006/11/my-eclipse-code-folding-plugin.html) is now available here, [download link is here](http://coffee-bytes.googlecode.com/svn/branches/fixes_04_09_27/distro/com.cb.eclipse.folding1.0.6.200611020605S%20.zip).

Comment: Download link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry; there is not.

There might be a plugin

Answer (score 0):

You must download Coffe-Bytes plugin and install to eclipse. 
url is here

https://code.google.com/p/coffee-bytes/source/browse/

Check bellow links about how can install eclipse plugin

1. [How to install plugin for Eclipse from .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip)
2. http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_install_new_plug-ins%3F